# WSUS Synchronization Schedule - Once per month?

Tags: wsus

WSUS has no option for syncing once per month. It requires a daily synchronization. Is it possible to change this to once per month through GPO or other means? Is the only other option to manually sync?

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do that. The files don't download a second time.. having them available locally as quickly as (reasonably) possible is a good idea.

Comment: Microsoft releases new updates the second Tuesday of every month. It's pretty rare for an update to be released "out of band". Assuming your WSUS server has completed a "full" sync at least once, then it should only be downloading new updates once a month every month. There's no need to try to "hard code" it to do so.

Comment: I believe you can start a synchronization via the WSUS API, so you could write a script and configure Task Scheduler to run once a month.

Comment: @joeqwerty, there's a second set of updates most months.  And I don't think one-off updates are quite as unusual as you suggest, particularly when updates have to be re-released due to some problem or other.  As for the reason the OP wants to do this, I'd be prepared to make a *small* bet that it is so they can use automatic approvals but still be sure the clients will only reboot once a month. :-)

Comment: @gibsonfirebird12, glad to hear it.  If you get it working, please consider posting the script as an answer.

Comment: @gibsonfirebird12 - I noticed that you did not respond to my answer! Is there anything which you'd like me to query further? Any improvements, etc. required?

Comment: This makes little sense - one thing overlooked is that it is not only updates, it is also anti virus and malware signatures that WSUS handles. Those come basically multiple times per day.

Answer (score 0):

> WSUS has no option for syncing once per month. It requires a daily
>   synchronization. Is it possible to change this to once per month
>   through GPO or other means?

You cannot achieve this directly from the native GUI of WSUS. It is not available as an option. Instead, [you can extend the capabilities of WSUS with a third-party application like SolarWinds Patch Manager](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/community/solarwinds-community/geek-speak/blog/2013/01/07/recommendations-for-synchronizing-your-microsoft-wsus-servers).

> Is the only other option to manually sync?

Preferably, if you've to, a better hack would be to set to manually perform the synchronisation in WSUS. And, then create a Windows task scheduler which would perform synchronisation with the help of available WSUS API. For more information, please refer to the post ["Synchronize WSUS update using command"](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/29f816e5-3156-4eae-9e06-0df8095b7182/synchronize-wsus-update-using-command?forum=winserverwsus).